# java.lang.NumberFormatException: in Pyspark when writing to S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read compressed log file from S3 bucket using pyspark on EC2 instance.
EC2 instance has read permission to S3 bucket as I am able to manually download the file using AWS CLI command.

This is how my code looks like

```
file_path= 's3a://<bucket_name>/<path_of_file>'

rdd1 = sc.textFile(file_path)

rdd1.take(3)
```

But I am getting below error

```
*py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.partitions.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "64M"*
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: did the below suggestion work for you? If so, please upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

you are mixing versions of hadoop-common with an older version of hadoop-aws.

the s3a connector added support for using a unit when declaring multipart block size in *2016*, eight years ago, in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13680.

hadoop-common JAR versions 2.8+ set it to "64M"

if the version of the s3a connector you are using can't cope with that, it means it is *nine years old*

please

1. upgrade your hadoop-* jars to a recent version, ideally 3.3.0+
2. make sure they are all the same version unless you enjoy seeing stack traces
3. and use the exact same aws-sdk-bundle jar which hadoop was built with unless you want to see different stack traces.

*thisis not an opinion, these are instructions from the hadoop-aws maintenance team*.

Comment: if anyone else has a different opinion, well, they didn't write the code in question, did they?